# LibreOffice calc formula: find the value for a given data based on known data

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-base

I have LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet with table that calculates cost for two services. I want calculate cost of service #2 based on known data. The known data are `rates` (0,80 and 0,68: its permanent) and `total incl.VAT 21%`. Variable data in column C (unknown): C2 always equal to C3. Based on known data, I want split "Total incl. VAT" amount into a two separate parts, service #1 and service #2 cost. In particular, I want know the 'service #2' amount with VAT. (D3 + VAT) Can someone show formula how to make this?

```
+---+------------+---------------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+
|   |     A      |       B       |        C        |    D     |        E        |
+---+------------+---------------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+
| 1 | services   | Rate (eur/m3) | volume, m3      | Sum(eur) | service #2 cost |
| 2 | service #1 | 0,80          | 71,00           | 56,80    |                 |
| 3 | service #2 | 0,68          | 71,00           | 48,28    |                 |
| 4 |            |               | Subtotal:       | 105,08   |                 |
| 5 |            |               | VAT 21%         | 22,07    |                 |
| 6 |            |               | Total incl. VAT | 127,15   | D3 value + VAT  |
+---+------------+---------------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Isn't it the same formula as the one for the total? Of course with another input value?

Comment: The table I posted was an example: the actual data I know is only C6 value (Total incl.VAT), values of B2 and B3 rates, and VAT rate. The rest data is unknown.

Comment: Do you stumble because you don't grasp the mathematics, or don't you know how to translate the mathematical expression to a spread sheet formula?

Comment: I stumbled because I'm not sure how to express it mathematically (mostly). I understand that this is based on some math. proportion.

Comment: So it is not a LibreOffice problem, but a mathematical problem.